# Python PostgreSQL: Scripting Trouble

Tags: python, postgresql, scripting

**The problem:** I run a python script that takes in as user input the user associated with a PostgreSQL database. The script opens the database creates the extension postgis and then alters some tables. I'm connecting just fine, and no messages are printed to the console when I run the script saying it didn't work, but the extension postgis is never installed and I don't know if the tables are altered correctly. This python script is called in a bash script and from it not working my bash won't later on. Any help would be great!

```
 import psycopg2
 import sys


 con = None
 argument = sys.argv[1]

 try:

     con = psycopg2.connect(database='gis', user=sys.argv[1])
     cur = con.cursor()
     cur.execute("CREATE EXTENSION postgis")
     cur.execute("ALTER TABLE geometry_columns OWNER TO %s" % argument)
     cur.execute("ALTER TABLE spatial_ref_sys OWNER TO %s" % argument)



     cur.execute('SELECT version()')
     ver = cur.fetchone()
     print ver


 except psycopg2.DatabaseError, e:
     print 'Error %s' % e
     sys.exit(1)


 finally:

     if con:
         con.close()
```

Comment: shouldn't you run a `cur.commit()` command to apply your changes?

Comment: I believe it would be con.commit() but either way great catch, I'll update if it worked.